# Equality proofs and pattern matching in total functions

Tags: idris

I know this is a bit contrived example, but I was wondering how do I make the following function total:

```
total foo : (x : Int) -> {auto prf : x = 10} -> Int
foo 10 = 10
```

At the moment type checker complains:

```
Main.foo is not total as there are missing cases
```

Edit:

Adding `impossible` branch to HTNWs answer I got it to typecheck this way:

```
total foo : (x : Int) -> {auto prf : x = 10} -> Int
foo 10 {prf = Refl} = 10
foo x {prf = Refl} impossible
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pattern match on the equality, too

```
total foo : (x : Int) -> {auto prf : x = 10} -> Int
foo 10 {prf=Refl} = 10
```

Comment: I still get `Main.foo is not total as there are missing cases` with pattern matched equality